# Approach clarification - ASP.NET multi-user portal design studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have to develop an application like Google Draw, not exactly the same. The purpose would be developing a Web APP Development IDE.
User base is expected to be high and for public use primarily.

*Platform : C# ASP.NET with MS SQL 2008 (I cant have a say on changing the platform anyways:(           )*

So assuming when a user drag-n-drops(accomplished with Javascript) a textbox(for example) onto the design pane we need to place equivalent HTML code for the textbox and the design pane gets updated. So for this kind of approach,

1. Is it good to have a AJAX post to server for every drag-n-drop the user makes, so the state is maintained in server side.

Cons: Server getting loaded high when the user counts raises up.

---

**or**

1. Is it good to have HTML code generation in the client side and queue the user actions and post in a frequent time interval?

Cons: The user may loose cached(persistent) data when browser data is cleared.

---

I am not sure whether there any other approach than both the above, both the above has its own pros and cons, but please advice on the same, it will be greatly helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the first option. Move to the second when the user base has grown and you notice delays (if you do so). It should be a small refactor process if you structure the client side properly.

You could also use HTML5 offline storage and sync when you can = no data is lost.

Comment: But the offline data storage can still be cleared right? correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: And will the client side will not become heavy to have the HTML templates for every HTML control dragged and dropped? or that size isn't a problem for the browser to load?

Comment: Yes it can. But is it likely that the user will do it during a session? Just have a "Save" button.

Comment: Ajax ***will*** have a delay for each operation. Do you really think that you users will accept that micro delay each time that they want to drag a new template?

Comment: We can also do a auto save after 120 secs and have a manual save button both. 
AJAX delay is not acceptable thats the main reason we want to find another approach for the same, for example the user goes offline unexpectedly the design view remains not updated.

Comment: I would have a save button and also try to save each operation. Seems like that easiest approach to start with.

Comment: You mean to say to use AJAX calls to save every operation in the server side ? if yes, we have tried this approach and not making much scalability here.